# Wordpress post enumeration

Tags: posts

I am using wordpress as a quick fix for a blog for my site. I am using a short loop in an external page (i got the links to use the wordpress set-up correctly):

```
query_posts('p='.$thisPost); //$thisPost enumerates 1,2..etc up to a maximum number of posts

<?php 
while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The issue that in the database the wordpress would store post #2 as "p=6", which essentially screws up this setup.

How would I get a post number 2 ( or 3 or n ) from the start?

Answer (score 0):

The database is not just storing the posts that you have created, it stores revisions of that post along with other post types, etc. all in this table.  So the post ids of the posts that we enter rarely go up one at a time.

The post ids themselves are not very relevant in the queries.  The specific queries are used to only show posts that have a certain criteria, such as category, post_type, date stored, etc.